# Why are styles not being included in index.html on the local server

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

Using node.js, I opened the server, why is it not showing the styles, although if you just open index.html in the browser, then all the styles are displayed correctly, what is the problem?
index.html

<!doctype html>

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
</head>
```

index.js

```
 const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const http = require('http');
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    const port = 3000;
    
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/style/style.css'));
    
    app.get('/', (request, response ) => {
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
    
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
    });
```

Comment: I think you should just use `href="style.css"`. Express will automatically look for the file in `__dirname + '/style/style.css'`, because this folder has been designed as containing static files. On the other hand, there's no explicit route for `style/` so Express returns a 404.

Comment: Repaired, helped __dirname + '/public' and index.html href='/style/style.css'

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'style'));
```

Instead. Express.static uses directories. Not files.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html